# Binding not updating in ComboBox Text field when underlying ComboBox item description changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, wpf-controls

I am having a binding update problem with my ComboBox.  My ComboBox's ItemSource is bound to a list of LaneConfigurations.  The ComboBox's SelectedItem is bound to the SelectedLaneConfiguration property in my code-behind.  I configured the ComboBox's ItemTemplate to display the 'DisplayID' property for each LaneConfiguration.

This works most of the time.  However, changing a lane configuration can result in the DisplayID changing.  If you have a particular lane selected and it's DisplayID is being displayed as the 'Text' of the ComboBox and then you change the LaneConfiguration object, the 'Text' portion of the ComboBox is not updated with the new 'DisplayID' that should be showing.  When I click the dropdown arrow on the ComboBox, the item appearing as the selected item in the list is showing the correct DisplayID, but that doesn't match the 'DisplayID' that is being shown at the top of the ComboBox in it's 'Text' field.

In my code behind, I am firing a PropertyChanged event on the 'SelectedLaneConfiguration' property.  How do I get the ComboBox to realize that the 'DisplayID' property needs updating?  I have tried to fire a PropertyChanged event for the 'DisplayID' property, but it is part of the LaneConfiguration class, so it doesn't appear to be updating.

I have included the XAML below along with a screenshot that shows the ComboBox Text display out of sync with the content of the ComboBox dropdown.

[image: ScreenShot]

Partial XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="_comboBoxLanes" Height="26"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SensorConfiguration.LaneConfigurations}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedLaneConfiguration}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayID, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Some of the code-behind:

```
    public partial class LaneManagement : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDisposable
    {
        ..
        ..

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void FirePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }

        private void SensorConfiguration_Changed()
        {
            LaneTools.ResetLanePolygons();
            GenerateLaneTypeDropdowns();
            FirePropertyChanged("SensorConfiguration");
            FirePropertyChanged("SelectedLaneConfiguration");
            FirePropertyChanged("DisplayID");
        }
   }


   public class LaneConfiguration : PolygonConfiguration
   {
       public override string DisplayID
       {
          get
          {
              return IsLaneGroup?string.Format("Lanes {0} - {1}", ID, ID + LaneCount - 1):                                  string.Format("Lane {0}", ID);
          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to see some of the C# code as well.

Comment: the LaneConfigurations must be inherit INotifyPropertyChanged, did you do it?

Comment: Show what you mean by "change the LaneConfiguration object"

Comment: I inherited and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and use it to notify when the SelectedLaneConfiguration changes, but I cannot seem to figure out how to notify when the 'DisplayID' property of the SelectedLaneConfiguration changes.

Comment: 'Change the LaneConfiguration object' means that I changed a property on it that should result in the 'DisplayID' text changing.  So the old lane count was 10, so the DisplayID property returned 'Lanes 1-10' and when I changed the lane count to 7, the DisplayID property will return 'Lanes 1-7'.  The problem is I can't figure out how to tell the ComboBox that the 'DisplayID' for the 'SelectedLaneConfiguration' needs to be updated.

Comment: Have you tried setting the binding update condition? 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Comment: Just tried setting UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged.  This updates the items in the ComboBox, but does not update the 'Text' for the selected item at the top of the combobox.

Comment: Post where the code where change the property value for DisplayID.  Post the code (get set) for the property DisplayID.

Comment: Blam, I've updated my code-behind.  The DisplayID property is part of the LaneConfiguration class.  FirePropertyChanged("DisplayID") uses the INotifyPropertyChanged event to notify the binding of the updated property.  However, it doesn't appear that FirePropertyChanged("DisplayID") is causing any update on the binding.

Comment: Wow.  So you verified FirePropertyChanged("DisplayID"); is fired but that does not cause a get?

Comment: Looks like I needed to also implement INotifyPropertyChanged on my data object 'LaneConfiguration' class.  That fixed the problem immediately.  <Smack head with hand>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a shorter example of this and reposted and got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056423/1342454).

I thought I only needed INotifyPropertyChanged on the code-behind.  I actually needed it in my data object LaneConfiguration class as well.  I should have paid closer attention to Ali Adl's comment.  It would have saved me a day of frustration..

Thanks Ali Adl  and  Tim for your helpful answers !!

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to make properties that you bindin-g - DependencyProperty - than you'll not have any problems with auto update.

If you use INotifyPropertyCahgnge than it must work, if it don't - check if PropertyChanged event == null.